# Well-Tempered not Clavier?

Tags: notation

This question was inspired by another on transposing instruments.

I know some other suites for the keyboard which cover all 12 major keys or all 24 major and minor keys.  However, I don't know any for non-keyboard instruments.  Are there any?

Some extra detail, added in an edit.

I would expect that strings, e.g. violin and cello, can easily play in any key so a suite of studies in all keys should be possible.  I guess that what motivated the WTC was a demonstration that a keyboard instrument could do it whereas it would not be so surprising that strings could do it.

My clarinet might be tricky in some unusual keys but it should be able to do it and it would be a good show of virtuosity to play a suite of pieces in all possible keys.

I am now tempted to write a string quartet transcription of the WTC.  A joke, I am not really arrogant to believe that I could do it justice but I would be interested to hear it if someone else did.

Comment: I'm only aware of an *Art of the Fuge* version for string quartet, recorded by the Emerson Quartet. Whether temperament applies to strings too is related to [this meta question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2754/2600).

Comment: @guidot Thanks.  I had not heard of that but I will have a look.  Using strings raises the possibility that each piece could be played in just tempered rather than well tempered intonation.  Nonetheless, interesting either way.

Comment: Encyclopedic answer is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_written_in_all_major_and/or_minor_keys

Comment: I have heard at least one prelude and fugue from the WTC played by a string quartet, so a transcription/arrangement for the whole thing probably exists. It was from a CD, so probably it was not a one-off thing.

Comment: “I would expect that strings, e.g. violin and cello, can easily play in any key” – not really. Yes, professional players will always manage it, but keys with more than 4 sharps or 3 ♭s definitely _are_ awkward.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, I should not have said "easily" but it is possible on the instrument unlike a keyboard instrument.

Answer (score 1):

Updating my comment: Beyond the *Art of the Fuge* the Emerson Quartet also did a recording of some well tempered clavier fugues, see [Deutsche Grammophon](http://www.deutschegrammophon.com/de/cat/4777458), and looking at the track list there should be some more recordings of Mozart KV 405 to find.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically almost only stringed keyboard instruments that can be tuned note-by-note with reasonable effort and play whole polyphonic pieces.

There are fretted viols with movable frets, but then the frets are per-instrument rather than per-string and thus you cannot use them for creating a full octave-based tempered tuning either.

Comment: I don't see the need for frets.  For example. I would expect that a violin could play in any well-tempered key.  What do they do in violin sonatas?  I would hope that they were in tune with the piano.  They have the option to play in a just tempered intonation but they are not obliged to.

Comment: It's been said that violins, like acapella voices, when playing with no other even tempered instruments, tend to revert to just intonation. Sorry, can't find a quote.